# Is there a function in PHP from which we can detect the type of IP?

Tags: php, web-applications, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I have a web application which takes the IP. I want to know if we
can use a function to detect the type of IP in PHP (IPv4 or IPv6)?

I know we can get the IP in PHP by using this:

```php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
```

This gives the IP address but I can't find the variable which gives what type of IP it got (IPv4, IPv6).

Any help or leads?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a regular expression? The patterns are clearly distinct...

Comment: yes i can but i was wondering does PHP gives this support or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can verify what type of IP address it is by using `filter_var`

For example

```
filter_var('127.0.0.1', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4); // true
filter_var('::1', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6); // true
```

Don't forget that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` (or any other `_X_` header) can be spoofed easily.